# Insert UUID with pg-promise

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express

I am developing a new server and I am trying to have a customer have a UUID identifier. I want to be able to push the customers name, parent company and internal id from a web interface but the uuid should be generated server side. How can I insert the UUID into the database? The uuid should be put into the ID in the table.

The current setup is so I can send the ID in with curl and have it all tested.
What the code was doing before was get every value from the terminal. I am trying to modify this working code so that when I create a new customer I can put their name, parent, symID and have a uuid generated into the ID column.

for the symID I also want to pull that from a database of ID's that I currently do not have access to. I do not know if this feature will be implemented so for right now it is just entered either manually or not at all.

I am using pg-promise to write to a postgres database, also using express and bluebird.

```
//Database setup
...
CREATE TABLE  customer(
  customer_name VARCHAR,
  ID varchar PRIMARY KEY,
  parent VARCHAR,
  symID VARCHAR
);
...

//code to create new user
...
function createUser(req, res, next) {
  const user_id = uuidv4();
  //need to fix id. currently it is user entered and not a uuidv4
  db.none('insert into customer values(${customer_name}, ${ID}, ${parent}, ${symID})',
    req.body)
    .then(function () {
      res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          message: 'Inserted one customer'
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return next(err);
  });
}
...
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Did you have a question? A list of desires doesn't require any help on our part.

Comment: I edited to make it clearer what I meant. I do not know how to add the uuid into the field where I need it.

Comment: You didn't indentify this either: _into the field where I need it_ - Your table has `customer_name`, `ID`, `parent`, `symID` - pick one. Also, is there a reason you don't have a comma between `${ID}` and `${parent}`?

Comment: What the code was doing before was get every value from the terminal. I am trying to modify this working code so that when I create a new customer I can put their name, parent, symID and have a uuid generated into the ID column.

Comment: replace `request.body` with an object containing those keys and values.

Comment: Sorry but I am new to the whole pg-promis and express. Do I just create a normal js object and put into all the values I want to pass in?

Comment: You should be doing it like this: https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/ParameterizedQuery.html

Comment: May be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270145/how-to-insert-a-record-with-a-uuid-array-into-a-pg-table-using-nodejs-pg-promise), not sure, as the question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the UUID automatically with minor change to your table definition:

if not already installed then you need the extension pgcrypto.

```
    CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;  -- if needed

    CREATE TABLE  customer(
      customer_name VARCHAR,
      ID uuid default gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
      parent VARCHAR,
      symID VARCHAR
    );
```

That will generate a type4 uuid. Getting it's value back would be similar to getting the PK created by sequence/serial ( at list I think so ).